# Enable tab auto completion for kubectl in bash function

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, bash-completion

Given a bash function in .bashrc such as

```
kgp () {
  kubectl get po -n $1 $2
}
```

Is it possible to have kubectl auto complete work for k8s resources such as namespaces/pods? As an example if I use

```
kubectl get po -n nsprefix podprefix
```

I can tab auto complete the prefix. Whereas with the positional parameters when I call

```
kgp nsprefix podprefix
```

I have to type out the entire resource name.

Comment: try `install bash-completion`

Comment: I already have bash completion installed. That dosen't work with the postional parameters I provide to my functions as explained above.

Comment: Not exact answer, but related (and can be made exact with a plugin)... I also searched similar tooling but end up creating a working POC instead: https://github.com/uvsmtid/argrelay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's because bash-completion only understands *known commands*, not aliases or new functions that you have made up. You will experience the same thing with a trivial example of `alias whee=/bin/ls` and then `whee <TAB>` will do nothing because it doesn't "recurse" into that alias, and *for sure* does not attempt to call your function in order to find out what arguments it could possibly accept. That could potentially be catastrophic

You're welcome to create a new [`complete`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion) handler for your custom `kgp`, but that's the only way you'll get the desired behavior

```bash
_kgp_completer() {
    local cur prev words cword

    COMPREPLY=()
    _get_comp_words_by_ref -n : cur prev words cword
    if [[ $cword == 1 ]] && [[ -z "$cur" ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(echo ns1 ns2 ns3) )
    elif [[ $cword == 2 ]] && [[ -z "$cur" ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(echo pod1 pod2 pod3) )
    fi
    echo "DEBUG: cur=$cur prev=$prev words=$words cword=$cword COMPREPLY=${COMPREPLY[@]}" >&2
}
complete -F _kgp_completer kgp
```

Comment: How about https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias?